# Pick item in array by percentage

Tags: ruby

I have an array which contains names and percentages.
Example: 
`[["JAMES", 3.318], ["JOHN", 3.271], ["ROBERT", 3.143]]`.
Now I have about a thousand of these names, and I'm trying to figure out how to choose a name randomly based on the percentage of the name (like how James as 3.318% and John as 3.271%), so that name will have that percentage of being picked (Robert will have a 3.143% of being picked). Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the percentages add up to 100?

Comment: Yeah, all the percentages add up to 100.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by): (the docs contain a similar example)

```
array.max_by { |_, weight| rand ** 1.fdiv(weight) }
```

This assumes that your weights are actual percentages, i.e. 3.1% has to be expressed as `0.031`. Or, if you don't want to adjust your weights:

```
array.max_by { |_, weight| rand ** 100.fdiv(weight) }
```

I'm using [`fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv) here to account for possible integer values. If your weights are always floats, you can also use `/`.

Comment: That's quite interesting. I read the doc, but it's not evident why it works and the paper on which it is based does not appear to be available for free. Do you understand the basis for max-bying `rand ** 100.fdiv(weight)`? I noticed that's the same as max-bying `(100.fdiv(weight))*log(rand)`.

Comment: Actually, the same as max-buying `log(rand)/weight`. Note `log(rand) < 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Even though I like @Stefan answer more than mine, I will contribute with a possible solution: I would distribute all my percentages along `100.0` so that they start from 0.0 and end to 100.0.
Imagine I have an array with the following percentages:

```
a = [10.5, 20.5, 17.8, 51.2]
```

where

```
a.sum = 100.0
```

We could write the following to distribute them along 100.0:

```
sum = 0.0
b = a.map { |el| sum += el }
```

and the result would be

```
b = [10.5, 31.0, 48.8, 100.0]
```

now I can generate a random number between 0.0 and 100.0:

```
r = rand(0.0..100.0) # or r = rand * 100.0
```

imagine r is `45.32`.

I select the first element of `b` that is >= r`

```
idx = b.index { |el| el >= r }
```

which in our case would return `2`.

Now you can select `a[idx]`.

But I would go with @Stefan answer as well :)

Comment: `rand(0.0..100.0)` → `rand * 100`. And to find an element there's `b.find { |el| el > r }`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your sentence, "I would distribute...end to 100"? The OP says there are about 1,000 percentages. Since they sum to 100 (and presumably all are positive) they must be floats. If you rounded off those percentages to the nearest whole percentage many would be zero and the rest would likely not sum to 100. Please explain how you would create your array `a` in this case.

Comment: @Stefan I don't need to find an element, but its index, since the element is in a different array in my case. I'll change my answer using numbers with decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will be drawing multiple random values, in which case efficiency is important. Moreover, I assume that all names are unique and all percentages are positive (i.e., that pairs with percentages of `0.0` have been removed).

You are given what amounts to a (discrete) probability density function (PDF). The first step is to convert that to a cumulative density function (CDF).

Suppose we are given the following array (whose percentages sum to 100).

```
arr = [["LOIS", 28.16], ["JAMES", 22.11], ["JOHN", 32.71], ["ROBERT", 17.02]]
```

First, separate the names from the percentages.

```
names, probs = arr.transpose
  #=> [["LOIS", "JAMES", "JOHN", "ROBERT"],
  #     [28.16, 22.11, 32.71, 17.02]]
```

Next compute the CDF.

```
cdf = probs.drop(1).
            each_with_object([0.01 * probs.first]) { |pdf, cdf|
              cdf << 0.01 * pdf + cdf.last }
  #=> [0.2816, 0.5027, 0.8298, 1.0]
```

The idea is that we will generate a (pseudo) random number between zero and one, `r` and find the first value `c` of the CDF for which `r <= c`.<sup>1</sup> To do this in an efficient way we will perform an intelligent search of the CDF. This is possible because the CDF is an increasing function.

I will do a binary search, using [Array#bsearch_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index). This method is essentially the same as [Array#bseach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) (whose doc is the relevant one), except the index of `cdf` is returned rather than the element of `cdf` is randomly selected. It will shortly be evident why we want the index.

```
r = rand
  #=> 0.6257547400776025
idx = cdf.bsearch_index { |c| r <= c }
  #=> 2
```

Note that we cannot write `cdf.bsearch_index { |c| rand <= c }` as `rand` would be executed each time the block is evaluated.

The randomly-selected name is therefore<sup>2</sup>

```
names[idx]
  #=> "JOHN"
```

Now let's put all this together.

```
def setup(arr)
  @names, probs = arr.transpose
  @cdf = probs.drop(1).
    each_with_object([0.01*probs.first]) { |pdf, cdf| cdf << 0.01 * pdf + cdf.last }
end

def random_name
  r = rand
  @names[@cdf.bsearch_index { |c| r <= c }]
end
```

Let's try it.  Execute `setup` to compute the instance variables `@names` and `@cdf`.

```
setup(arr)
@names
  #=> ["LOIS", "JAMES", "JOHN", "ROBERT"]
@cdf
  #=> [0.2816, 0.5027, 0.8298, 1.0]
```

and then call `random_name` each time a random name is wanted.

```
5.times.map { random_name }
  #=> ["JOHN", "LOIS", "JAMES", "LOIS", "JAMES"]
```

<sup>1. This is how most discrete random variates are generated in simulation models.</sup>

<sup>2. Had I used `bsearch` rather than `bsearch_index` I would have had to earlier create a hash with `cdf=>name` key-value pairs in order to retrieve a name for a given randomly-selected CDF value.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to the problem:

```
array = [["name1", 33],["name2", 20],["name3",10],["name4",7],["name5", 30]]

def random_name(array)
  random_number = rand(0.000..100.000) 
  sum = 0

array.each do |x|
  if random_number.between?(sum, sum + x[1])
    return x[0]
  else
    sum += x[1]
  end
end
end

puts random_name(array)
```

Comment: shouldn't that be rand(0.000..100.000) on line 4 ?

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I edited the rand with and comma instead of between.